# Canvas: Lines not rendered fully on Windows

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

In my React application, I have a video-element, which I grab a frame from, and add to a canvas.
I then let the user draw on the canvas using their mouse. On Mac (Latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari) this works perfectly. On windows, there are problems with the lines not being drawn completely.

I made a codesandbox with the reproduced problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jnj2q63z4v

Steps to reproduce:

1. Wait for the video to load.
2. Click the screenshot button.
3. Try to draw on the canvas. I think the bug is easiest to reproduce if you try to draw counter-clockwise circles.

Comment: I started looking into your problem (and I witnessed the gaps in drawing under Windows + Chrome), and the weirdest thing happened after I added a console.log in the part of the drawing event handler where a point is actually drawn to the canvas - I didn't have gaps anymore! See https://codesandbox.io/s/4298nlpw87

Comment: This might have to do with how painting the screen is done under Windows, and the console.log slowing the processing enough that every single point is actually painted? Just a guess...

Comment: Please include an [MCVE] in the question itself.

Comment: Note that every time you call stroke() the whole Path is rendered, this mens all the points from your mousedown are layered again and again at each mousemove.